# Pseudo Element ::before Hiding Sibling Element's Content

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I want to create a transition effect when hovering over my list element (or alternatively my anchor tags within these list elements).

Unfortunately, when I use my created transition the ::before pseudo-element (or the ::after, I'm not sure) are hiding what is technically its sibling content, that being the text within the anchor tags.

I've tried manipulating the z-index on the ul, li and a tags to no avail. The problem likely lies within my use of position: absolute in my transitions but I can't tell what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the HTML and CSS and a [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/htawa9n5/)

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#headercontainer {
    background-color: #4f2f65;
    height: 125px;
    position: relative;
}

#headercontainer ul {
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#sitelogo {
    padding-top: 0px;
}

#headercontainer ul li {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
}

#headercontainer ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 0px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
}

a:hover::before {
    height: 125px;
}

header::after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

#headerlinkslist a:hover {
    color: red;
}

.headerlinks {
    padding-left: 80px;
    padding-right: 80px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="headercontainer">
            <ul id="headerlinkslist">
                <li id="sitelogo"></li>
                <li><a href="" class="headerlinks">RULES</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="headerlinks">NEWS</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="headerlinks">STATS</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="headerlinks">SUBMIT</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="headerlinks">LOGIN / REGISTER</a></li>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the transition that you are hoping to achieve?

Comment: @Ryan the OP's transition is hiding the link text when the link is hovered.

Comment: A reproducible snippet of the issue should be present *in the question itself*. Please edit your question to include all code necessary to replicate the issue, preferably as a runnable SO-snippet. *(Not an external resource like JSFiddle)*

Comment: Is there any possibilty of adding an additional element inside the anchor tags (i.e. a span tag)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

give the parent `li` a `z-index`, then use `z-index: -1` on the pseudo element to push it behind the `a` but on top of the `li`.

You also need to close your `ul`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#headercontainer {
  background-color: #4f2f65;
  height: 125px;
  position: relative;
}

#headercontainer ul {
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#sitelogo {
  padding-top: 0px;
}

#headercontainer ul li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

#headercontainer ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color .25s;
}

a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
  z-index: -1;
}

a:hover::before {
  height: 125px;
}

header::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

#headerlinkslist a:hover {
  color: red;
}

.headerlinks {
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-right: 80px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div id="headercontainer">

      <ul id="headerlinkslist">
        <li id="sitelogo"></li>
        <li><a href="" class="headerlinks">RULES</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="headerlinks">NEWS</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="headerlinks">STATS</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="headerlinks">SUBMIT</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="headerlinks">LOGIN / REGISTER</a></li>

       </ul>
    </div>

  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Nice elegant solution. Well done, dude. I'd also add a transition to the color parameter of the anchor tags, as well (just personal opinion, though).

Comment: @MichaelCoker Thank you so much, I greatly appreciate a clear and succinct answer such as this one. :)

Question though: why did I have to give my li element a z-index of 0? Should that not have been 0 by default? 

I'll be changing the color parameter of the anchor tags to be the same purple as the background, forgot to mention that.

Comment: @TTBDV you're welcome :) When you set an element to `z-index: -1`, it will go behind all elements that do not have a declared `z-index`. So try removing the `z-index` from the `li`. You'll see the hover effect goes under your header container. To keep that from happening, you want to add a `z-index` to either `#headercontainer`, `#headerlinkslist` or the `li`'s.